# jQuery autocomplete won't show more than 10 results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete, and no matter what settings I change, I can't get it to show more than 10 results in the dropdown.  I can see in the results coming back that I'm getting all of them from the server, but the front end won't show more than 10.

```
$("#add_cpt_code_text").autocomplete('<%: Url.Action("SearchCPT", "ChargeCapture") %>', {
    autoFill: false,
    mustMatch: true,
    matchContains: true,
    cacheLength: 1,
    maxItemsToShow: 15,
    minChars: 3,
    extraParams: {
        LocationID: 0
    },
    formatItem: function (data, index, max) {
        return data[1];
    },
    formatMatch: function (data, index, max) {
        return data[1];
    },
    formatResult: function (data, index, max) {
        return data[1];
    }
}).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
    if (data) {
        $("#add_cpt_code_id").val(data[0]);
        $("#add_cpt_code_text").val(data[1]);
    }
    else {
        $("#add_cpt_code_id").val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe you have  a link for that?

Comment: Are you sure the target element('s wrapper) doesn't have a certain fixed height, thereby limiting the results that are actually visible?

Comment: Which jquery autocomplete plugin is that ?  It isnt jqueryUI.autocomplate (UI 1.8.6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, I need to use max, not maxItemsToShow

I was using the jquery-ui autocomplete