# jQueryUI autocomplete not displaying more than 10 results to the user

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am currently using jquery-ui-1.8.10
I am using the autocomplete component and cannot find in the documentation any way to configure it to return more than 10 results to the user, even though the list has more than 10 results returned from the server.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Here is a similar post, but max does not work for me and it feels like he is using another component other than the autocomplete one from jQueryUI, even though he says he is.
[jQuery autocomplete won't show more than 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010767/jquery-autocomplete-wont-show-more-than-10-results)

How can I configure the component to display more than 10 results to the user?

```
$("#module-name-search").autocomplete({
        source: "service/searchForModule?langCode=" + langCode,
        minLength: 3,
        max: 50,
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#module-code-search").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#module-name-search").val(ui.item.text);

            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a style='font-size:9px;'>" + item.text + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't override the _renderItem function? If you set minLength to 0, pull the JS console up and do $("#module-name-search").autocomplete.("search"), do you still see just 10 results?

Comment: I do not have the code with me as yet, and only got onto stack overflow now again. Going to try set it to email me when someone replies. I did find a fix, will hunt the code and post an update to what worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem... posted below is the code.

```
$("#module-name-search").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            if (searchAjax != null) {
            searchAjax.abort();
        }
        searchAjax = $.ajax({
                url: "service/searchForModule?langCode=" + langCode,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: encodeURI(request.term),
                    iTipeProgram: $("#prog-type-input").val()
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    //alert(data);
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#module-code-search").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#module-name-search").val(ui.item.text);

            return false;
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a style='font-size:9px;'>" + item.text + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
```